# How to your Discord account creation and add it to an embed?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am wondering how to your Discord account creation. I would also like to know how to put it in a embed. Yes I do know how to make an embed, but how to insert it.

Comment: what do you mean with your first question?!

Answer (score 0):

By `Discord account creation`, I will assume you are referring the `User#createdAt` property - which returns a Date object containing when the user account was created.

**Note 1.** You can convert a Date object to a pretty time string by calling `Date.toUTCString()`, or similar methods (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date))

Adding it to an embed seems pretty straightforward to me.

By then, your code should look like:

```js
const user = getSomeUserHere() //for example, you can do message.author to get the User object of the message's author
const createdDate = user.createdAt

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("This user was created at")
.setDescription(`${createdDate.toUTCString()}`);

message.channel.send(embed) //or however you plan to send this embed
```